# How can I filter a picker by the selected item of another picker in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have data stored in a SQLite database in my Xamarin.Forms app that looks like this:

1. A
2. A
3. A
4. A
5. B
6. B
7. B
8. C

etc. etc.

Two columns, one as a distinct list of values and the other as a "category". I have a picker with the categories, and all I'd like to be able to do is select a category, then only show the values in that category in a second picker. E.g. selecting "B" in Picker 1 filters Picker 2's options to be 5, 6, and 7. I have an event handler set up for SelectedIndexChanged of Picker 1, but I just don't know what to set as Picker 2's ItemsSource in terms of SQLite.

EDIT: Found a solution, posting for future reference. This code works out of Picker 1's created event handler.

```
private void Picker1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                var assets = conn.Table<Values>();
                Picker2.ItemsSource = conn.Query<Values>("select * from Values where Category = ?", Picker1.SelectedItem);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ and filter the items for the Picker 2 based on the Selected value of Picker 1

You can handle this in SelectedIndexChanged of Picker 1:

```
Picker2.ItemSource = db.Query<TableName>().ToList().Where(x => x.Property == e.SelectedItem).
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however it seems like my SelectedIndexChanged event handler doesn't contain a definition for SelectedItem?

Comment: See answer, used Picker1.SelectedItem instead of e.SelectedItem.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that you retrieve all the data at once, rather than selecting Picker1 every time, querying the database once more, and populating Picker2 again.
This will depend heavily on the network and affect interactivity.

So, we can get the required data at once according our data struct.

I created a simple demo to simulate the function,the main code is:

class `ValueModel`

```
public  class ValueModel
{
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}
```

class `CategoryModel`

```
 public class CategoryModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ValueModel> values { get; set; }

    public CategoryModel()
    {
        values = new ObservableCollection<ValueModel>();
    }
}
```

class `CategoryViewModel`

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }

    public CategoryViewModel()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
   <StackLayout>
    <Picker Title="select category" x:Name="CategoryPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CategoryName}" SelectedIndexChanged="DiameterPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"></Picker>
    <Picker Title="select value" x:Name="ValuePicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ValueName}"></Picker>
   </StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>() {
            new CategoryModel{CategoryName="A",values= {new ValueModel{ ValueName="1" }, new ValueModel { ValueName = "2" }, new ValueModel { ValueName = "3" } ,new ValueModel{ ValueName="4"}} },
             new CategoryModel{CategoryName="B",values= {new ValueModel{ ValueName="5" }, new ValueModel { ValueName = "6" }, new ValueModel { ValueName = "7" } } }
        };

        CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
        categoryViewModel.Categories = categories;

        BindingContext = categoryViewModel;

    }

    private void DiameterPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CategoryViewModel viewModel = BindingContext as CategoryViewModel;
        ValuePicker.ItemsSource = viewModel.Categories[((Picker)sender).SelectedIndex].values;
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, however is there any way I can do this without manually creating a new CategoryModel for every value? My actual data has quite a few more categories than A, B, C, and there are somewhere close to 700 values, so doing this manually is not very efficient at all. Thanks again.

Comment: The best way to do this is to process the logic on the back end of the server and return the required data directly to the client through the API, which is one of the most common methods.And we also do not need to manually creating a new CategoryModel for every value.